How does anti-reflective coating increase light passing through the glass?
How anti-reflective coating works is that it makes the light reflected from the air-coating interface and light reflected from the coating-glass interface cancel each other (destructive interference at half wavelength phase difference), thereby reducing the glare.
But how does it increase the light passing through the glass? There is still a certain amount of reflection whether there's a coating or not, it's just that they cancel out when there's a coating. The wavefronts of canceled reflections travel away from the interfaces. They do not reverse direction, right? How is it that more light passes through the glass? I'm confused.

For an extreme example, consider the Fabry Perot etalon.

A single photon has a higher probability of traversing the glass if the thickness (of the glass or the AR layer)  is close to a multiple of the wavelength.  The EM field of the photon is resonant with the glass/layer EM field.  Photons cancelling is outdated 1920s theory, QM knows that each photon does its own thing.

That's a good point

Light passing through the coating interferes constructively with light that has passed through the coating, reflected off the glass, and reflected again off of the outer surface of the coating. In that sense, the light reverses direction.

Comparing to glass without coating where the light gets reflected only at air-glass interface, with coating the light is now reflected twice (at air-coating interface and coating-glass interface), is it true that less light will pass through the glass?

@techie11 don't forget that there'll be at least one more reflection on coating-air interface, which is crucial for functioning of the coating. It's this very reflected wave that will contribute to constructive interference with the wave that has passed through the coating-glass interface before (when this secondary wave passes into the glass). And it's also the wave that will interfere destructively with the initial reflected wave that exited the coating into the air (when the secondary wave doesn't get reflected from the coating-air interface).

That's true. But the third reflected light is very small portion of the original intensity. Suppose the reflectance at all interfaces is 0.9, then the portion of the third reflected light entering the glass would be 0.9x0.1x0.1x0.9=0.0081. almost negligible.

@techie11 Remember that what superimposes is amplitude, which is the square root of intensity.

The answer to your question, But how does it increase the light passing through the glass?, is very simple and it is, less is reflected!
You may think that this is a stupid answer but consider another example, two slit interference which results in a series of light and dark fringes being seen after light has passed through the double slit.
The effect of the double slits is to change the direction of the light passing through the slits such that along certain directions there is a lot of light (bright fringes) and in other directions there is very little light (dark fringes) but overall there is no loss of energy.
This is precisely what is happening in the coating case, more light is transmitted and less is reflected.
Explaining the mechanism for this happening classically is based upon the idea that there is superposition of light waves reflected, ie travelling in the opposite direction to the incident light, from each side of the coating which are out of phase with one another.
This is an idea which does predict what is actually observed but one cannot actually observe the two individual reflected waves which are out of phase with one another, rather all one can do is 'imagine' that is what happens.
